# jQuery - Fire event at the end of a session?

Tags: jquery, session

Is it possible to fire an event at the END of a users session?

What I'm trying to achieve is to set a cookie based on the response to a 'pop up' question. If the answer is YES i'd like to redirect somewhere at the end of a session.

Is this possible?

Comment: well, how have you planned your session.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this on each page or AJAX load:

```
clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);
sessionTimeout = setTimeout(onSessionEnd, TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES*60*1000);
```

the function `onSessionEnd()` will get called when the session times out. As far as I know, the JS can't pick it out from the cookie, you need to tell your code what the timeout will be.